# InitializeComponent asynchrounously

Tags: asynchronous, initializecomponent

Is it possible to make asynchronous `InitializeComponent`? Otherwise could I load my WPF component asynchronously? More specifically I'm currently developping a product in WPF and I noticed that the loading time of graphical components (some components) is quite big when I have performance requirements.

Comment: wich kind of component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a component on the UI thread so there's no way to put `InitializeComponent` on another thread, but it can be called asynchronously in the same thread using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` as follows:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>InitializeComponent()));
```